# Who acted as the masked killer in Happy Death Day?

Tags: casting, happy-death-day

I know the person who try to kill (killed several times :P) *Tree* is *Lori Spengler* in the film. We find it out at the end of the movie.

At the first time when the killer shown and killed Tree he looked like a man, may be the movie makers want to confuse us.

And Lori is a slim girl. So I was wondering, is *Ruby Modine aka Lori* really acted as killer in all scenes? ( we see she removing the mask, when Tree tells she was the killer) or was it some other person?

Comment: It's probably the [stunt double](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm5437764/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr99) of Ruby Modine.

Comment: Couldn't the masked killer have been Lori Spengler in some instances and Joseph Tombs in others?  It has been a while since I saw the movie, so I don't clearly remember.

Comment: IMD indicates that Andy Dylan, the stunt double of Rob Mello, is the stunt performer of the Killer. It indicates that neither Ruby Modine nor Rob Mello did performer of the Killer in these scenes. https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5308322/fullcredits

Comment: It would have to be Lori for pretty much any attempt that wasn't around the hospital.  Tombs did not actually know Lori, so hunting her down at the party, outside the doctor's house, etc would have been pretty much impossible for him.  He would also most likely attack someone who he found to be an easy opportunity, while Lori would have been actively looking for Tree specifically.